# AWS S3 File Browser for Windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any official AWS *GUI* like S3 file explorer for Windows?

I know there's plenty non-official like [S3 Browser](https://s3browser.com/) but, I am avoiding using third-party software.

Comment: The AWS Console is official, but it's not a windows app. I use Cloudberry Explorer occasionally, but mostly I use the AWS console or AWS CLI.

Answer (score 3):

There’s none. Stick with S3 Browser as other options suck even more. Say CloudBerry has data integrity issues so things you copy to AWS or back on-site might come up damaged. Good review of the popular tools with the functionality you want is here:

https://proprivacy.com/cloud/comparison/amazon-s3-user-interface-tools